# Drawing with RGB colours taken from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, colors, rgb

I'm trying to draw a logo using Javascript, and I need to choose a random colour from a fixed palette.

I've established the colour palette as an array of RGB values, and then I am using a random number to pick one of the colours from the array.

I'd like to use the result as the colour of a circle drawn with a canvas arc.

So, this is the code I have so far...

```
// Define colour palette

var DarkColourPalette = [
{ r:45, g:10, b:55 }, // Dark purple
{ r:70, g:10, b:40 }, // Dark plum
{ r:0, g:5, b:70 },   // Dark blue
{ r:45, g:45, b:55 }, // Dark grey
{ r:50, g:40, b:40 }, // Dark brown
{ r:0, g:45, b:30 }   // Dark green
];
var DarkColours = DarkColourPalette.concat();

// Draw O

  contxt.beginPath();
  contxt.arc(75, 40, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  contxt.lineWidth = 10;
  contxt.strokeStyle = "rgba(DarkColours[0],1)";
  contxt.stroke();
```

Which should draw a Dark purple circle, but no matter what I try, I've not been able to get the context.strokeStyle bit to accept the colour values from the array. It just uses black.

Here's what it looks like with the colour values inserted manually:
http://codepen.io/RichardHolt/pen/mRRbpR

I'm new to this sort of thing. Am I just getting the syntax wrong here or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: if DarkColours[0] contains "45,10,55" you can use :

    contxt.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + DarkColours[0] + ",1)";

Comment: you need to draw circle with different color everytime that function is called? or page is loaded, or you want that circle should have different colors at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
contxt.strokeStyle = "rgba("+DarkColourPalette[0]["r"]+","+DarkColourPalette[0]["g"]+","+DarkColourPalette[0]["b"]+",1)";
```

or make it more readable like

```
"rgba(R,G,B,1)"
               .replace("R",DarkColourPalette[2].r)
               .replace("G",DarkColourPalette[2].g)
               .replace("B",DarkColourPalette[2].b);
```

`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in color pallate array and defined colors in form of string rather than object. Now everytime page loads you are getting circle with random color within defined colors of color pallate.

```
// Define colour palette

var DarkColourPalette = [
"rgba(45,10,55,1)", // Dark purple
"rgba(70,10,40,1)", // Dark plum
"rgba(0,5,70,1)", // Dark blue
"rgba(45,45,55,1)", // Dark grey
"rgba(50,40,40,1)", // Dark brown
"rgba(0,45,30,1)" //Dark Green
];
var DarkColours = DarkColourPalette.concat();

var canvas = document.getElementById('iON');
var contxt = canvas.getContext('2d');

contxt.scale ( 4,4 );

// Draw O

contxt.beginPath();
contxt.arc(75, 40, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
contxt.lineWidth = 10;
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1; // If you want to generate random number between 0-6
console.log(DarkColourPalette[index]);
contxt.strokeStyle = DarkColourPalette[index];
contxt.stroke();
```

Please find updated [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBBvrY).